# I cannot find the source list for installing Hydro for ubuntuARM

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you can see on the webpage of installation tutorial of Hydro for ubuntuARM
There is no source lists in 2.3 Setup your sources.list.

What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146001/i-cannot-find-the-source-list-for-installing-hydro-for-ubuntuarm/) by [seongyun](https://answers.ros.org/users/12841/seongyun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seongyun](https://answers.ros.org/users/12841/seongyun/) on 2014-03-29**:
I here link the URL, http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed. It looks like the most recent edit to that page removed the source listings.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0